# dle проверка на нахождении в категории

Tags: php, dle

Нужно в fullstory.tpl, в материалах отдельной категории выводить сообщение
Каким образом это можно сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для кастомизации страницы материала в зависимости от категории используется макрос `catlist`

Пример использования:

```
[catlist=4] Я в категоии 4 [/catlist]
[not-catlist=4] Я не в категоии 4 [/not-catlist]
```